# How do I set up Launchy's Runner plugin to launch Everything search

Tags: launchy, everything

I'm trying to configure Everything 1.3.3.658 with Launchy 2.5.0

From command line

```
everything.exe -search foo
```

This works pretty much as expected.

What I would like to do is run this command from Launchy, which seems possible with its Runner plugin.

I've given the Runner command the name: `search`

Set the Program to `C:/Program Files/Everything/Everything.exe`

Set the arguments to: `-search $$` (where $$ is supposed to mark the location for user input)

Then when I bring up Launchy with my keyboard shortcut and type

```
search (tab press:) foo
```

Everything opens, but I get the following error:

> Unable to open the file list:
>   C:\Users\helga\AppData\Roaming\Everything\foo not found

I don't understand why it is looking for a file list instead of running the search and can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer.  With Launchy 2.5.0, I am able to set up Everything as a runner task with the following settings

program:
`C:/Program Files/Everything/Everything.exe` (path to Everything.exe)

arguments:
`-s " $$`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working by following the lifehacker article here: http://lifehacker.com/5274774/integrate-everything-search-tool-and-launchy

And changing arguments from "C:\Program Files\Everything\Everything.exe" -search " to **"C:\Program Files\Everything\Everything.exe" -s "**. I suspect a similar change would help with the runner scenario.

Comment: Thanks for this! I now have `-s " $$` set up as the Runner parameters and this *finally* seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when upgrading everything to the latest version. I was using the lifehacker shortcut, but couldn't make it work with that method.

I was able to get it working with version 1.3.4.686 by doing the following:

- Set up a runner command.
- Choose a name. The name can be whatever you want, I chose f for the shortcut.
- In the Program section, enter "C:\Program Files\Everything\Everything.exe -s" (Sans quotes)
- In the Arguments, enter "$$" (with quotes)

This should do the trick for you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I upgraded to Everything 1.3 (x64). However, Everything 1.2 (x86) works perfectly on my 64-bit machine.

I suggest rolling back to the earlier version as a workaround. (That's what I ended up doing.) It's still available on the voidtools website.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought 1.3 got rid of the UAC notices though. I've basically just switched to using the Everything keyboard shortcut instead of Launchy, but this is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

So, the following commands works **only with x86** version of Everything and *not with 64-bit* version:

Go to :
**C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Everything**

Right click on "Search Everything" and see properties. Enter following in target (including quotes):
**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Everything\Everything.exe" -search "**

You may also rename this Link to something of your preference, say - "find"
Re-scan Launchy catalog to index the new name.

You are done !!!

```
Verifed it on Win7 and Win10.
```

Comment: Several people have already mentioned `-s`.  Is this just the verbose version of the same parameter?

Comment: I tried with, -s but it did not work for me. I think some of them have also mentioned same. I had been using -search since sometime, so shared same.

Answer (score -1):

I want to add the following additional point to answers:

If your Launchy runner command is similar named to any applications name in Windows's start menu then Launchy will randomly either call the start menu's app or the runner-command. So if for example you want to name your runner command "ever" (for everything) you have to rename or remove the search everything application entry in windows start menu.

Comment: Very ironic that I get -2 points for writing my comment about an additional workaround I had to make another answer working for me because I'm not allowed as a new active user to write comments. Very encouraging for new members.

Comment: There is a reason for [this](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: "Very ironic that I get -2 points for writing my comment" - The reason you are receiving down votes is because, instead of submitting a comment like you are suppose to do, you submitted an answer  Besides if your comment actually answers the question, then it isn't a comment, but an answer (but even you are calling this answer a comment) so it can't possible be an answer..  The good news, your answer will likely be deleted by the community for being a comment, which means any reputation you might have lost due to the down votes will be returned to you.

Comment: I caution you from submitting comments as an answer in the future though.  Answers which are down voted, even if they are deleted, caught towards or against your ability to submit new answers in the future.